# Can i create a LOGON trigger to change the value of 'STATUS' on a table when the user login in? | SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The idea is to Update the status of the User on User's Table during the login process using a trigger. The LOGON trigger will only fire on that database only

It is possible to do? plus a trigger that will change that value when the user closes the session.

The purpose of this is to make sure that the PROCEDURE'S that check the condition and let the user know the 'it's not available', when the user isn't logged in.

This is for a school project, it's not ideal.

Comment: What happens if the `LOGIN` logs in twice? A `LOGIN` can have multiple active connections. This sounds like an [XY problem](//xyproblem.info) if i am honest.

Comment: You can create a logon trigger with no issues, but there's no such thing as a logoff trigger, so this isn't going to work. You could try creating your view on top of `sys.dm_exec_sessions`/`connections`, but be aware that most applications use connection pooling, so a user could be "logged on" for a long time without actually being active or blocking anything.

Comment: Valid points, i was trying minimize stuff that users had to do. But sounds like it's not gonna be feasible.